# System.Drawing missing assembly or reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, xna, .net-assembly

I want to use the Bitmap class under an XNA project declared on System.Drawing but it says that I'm missing an assembly or reference. I added System.Drawing to my references and changed my target framework after seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553136/system-drawing-namespace-not-found-under-console-application). I opened 3 or 4 new projects doing the same but nothing changes. I am about to go crazy. What's the deal with this?

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Drawing;` on top of your code file? What are the exact compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the identifier. In the context menu, you should see <kbd>Resolve… ▹</kbd>. If you have already added the reference, it should add the code necessary to get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Drawing namespace is not usually added as a reference when you create a new project. If you look in the solution explorer for you project you should notice an expandable menu called References. Right click -> Add reference then select the .net tab and choose System.Drawing from the list.

Hope this helps.