# Can´t instantiate some .NET objects

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to instantiate the `System.Drawing.Graphics` object but for some reason Visual Studio can´t find the class. It seems that this is the case for some, but not all classes from the .NET Library.

I already checked the target framework and tried to instantiate with the Namespace. Also, there is no option for resolving it in the Visual Studio menu so it seems like Visual Studio doesnt even know the Object.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Media;


namespace Notify.Classes
{
    class NotificationDrawer
    {
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);

        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));

        g.Dispose();
        ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I had to bet it's this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8553136/1348195

Comment: `Graphics` doesn't have a public constructor.  It has some factory methods   What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No its not, i already checked as i said in the question.

Comment: @CharlesMager Doesnt matter, this is just a sample code. It cant find the class, has nothing to do with a missing constructor

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Drawing`?

Comment: @CharlesMager Lol, didnt check that :D Thanks, helped. If you post it as an answer i will accept it ;)

Comment: Everything about your code is strange. Your example code wouldn't even compile even if Graphics class was found. And you are trying to access a private constructor of the Graphics class.

Comment: This is sample code.

Comment: @mstorm sample code has to be valid to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `System.Drawing.Graphics` is in the `System.Drawing` assembly.

Ensure you have a reference to `System.Drawing`.