# Bitmap object not present in system.drawing?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to create a bitmap object in C# in Visual Studio 2019, but it isn't working. I have .NET Framework updated to the latest version and I have resharper installed. I am using Windows 10.

Ive tried adding the references manually with Add/Reference... and it does not stay checked.
I added `using system.drawing` and `using system.drawing.common` to the top of my code.
I updated my .net core and enabled it in my project.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Common;

namespace Bot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to create a bitmap object, but it won't compile and gives me errors saying that the bitmap object does not exist in `system.drawing`.

Comment: You need to add reference to ```System.Drawing.dll```, read the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553136/system-drawing-namespace-not-found-under-console-application).

Comment: Have you installed the `System.Drawing.Common` NuGet package? When you have, add `using System.Drawing;`, then write `var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);` (you need to specify a size or a source Image or a file path or a stream).

Comment: How do I install that? Sorry, I just started learning C# and VS a month ago

Comment: `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager - Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`. Search `System.Drawing.Common` and install it, ticking all the checkboxes (`Project`) you find in the panel on the right.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! In your case do Tag .NET Core!

Answer (score 3):

The `Bitmap` class if part of the assembly `System.Drawing.Common.dll`, so you need to install `System.Drawing.Common` via the Nuget Package.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the package in your system/project.
In you're project directory or from VScode terminal do this:

```
dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common --version 6.0.0
```

then add a reference to the package in you're project