# Using System.Drawing; in VS-Community 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I am developing a program in C# which should include graphic output. I was used to commonly use Drawing library by adding it to references in project tree, but this seems to be different now, because it no longer works for me.

I can see `System.Drawing.dll` reference in SDK bundle in the project structure, and as well I managed to add the reference manually into the project build, but once I try to write some code, intellisense doesn't provide any classes from given library such as `SolidBrush`, `Color` etc.

I would like to add reference to `System.Drawing` and use its classes in my code. I've struggled with this for more than a week. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of project do you have, and is it 2019 or 2015 after all?

Comment: What type of project?  In WinForms, System.Drawing is included automatically. No changes since VS2003.

Comment: It is to be included in WinForm but at the moment I am runnin algorithm tests in console. I just need to draw the output in some jpg file. Thanks Jakub

Comment: Have you actually [added a reference to System.Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553144/11683), which console apps lack? And is you console app [Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40892189/11683) by any chance?

Comment: I will take a look and share some screens when Im home

Comment: Ok, the problem is now following. I can use the Drawing Library, but only by specifying whole namespace f.e System,Drawing.Color even though i wrote using System.Drawing; in the beginning of the document. Another thing is that it only offers few classes like Rectangle, Size etc. . Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer but where I work we use VS 2019 and I came across the same problem:

The intellisense did not find `System.Drawing.Image`, but we too saw that it is in the reference (`System.Drawing`).

The solution: In the Package Manager we found a package named `System.Drawing.Common`. This had `Bitmap` and `Image` and now it works.

Actually this was the solution for some of us, but not all. One of my colleagues still has this problem even with the installed package.